# Unsetting Cookies for Logging out

Tags: php, cookies

So i'm trying to unset a cookie, as shown in my php book which explains to do something to this effect in the logout page

```
           if (!isset($_COOKIE['Username'])){
            require ('LoginFunctions.inc.php');
            redirect_user();
        } else {
            unset($_COOKIE['Username']);
            setcookie ('Username', '', time()-3600, '/', '', 0, 0);
            require ('index.php');
            redirect_user();
        }
```

However doing so should take me from the homepage (or any page), log me out, and then return me to the homepage. But it doesn't. On the homepage, when i click the logout link the page just "flashes" (representing direction to an automatically redirecting page, like it should) but doesn't log me out.

This brings me to another question. In this, i've written

```
if (!isset())
```

which means, if is not set, right? As such, why does the following snippet of code from the homepage work as if a username has been set as a cookie.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Username'])){
     $q2 = "SELECT * FROM user";
```

Because the code reads as "If Cookie is not set then.." and yet it treats it as if the cookie is set (selecting the correct user from the database and everything).

Comment: are you sure all the cookie business is happening before regular (body) output?

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons that come to mind

- either the time difference between the server and the client is more than an hour
- or the cookie has been set differently than you're unsetting it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set with. If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration time to one year in past.